# Непонятный контент получаю через HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался скачиваю через HttpClient адрес
 http://www.wordreference.com/definition/like в ответ получаю это

[image: пример]

Это, что зашифрованный контент, который потом через скрипты раскрывает браузер?
Или это что-то другое? На всякий случай поясняю: я пробовал свой код на других сайтах, и там все ОК, и я сомневаюсь, что дело в кодировке.

**P.S.** для разжатия следует использовать `HttpClientHandler`

```
    private static async Task<string> GetAnswerAsync(string request)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        };

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(request))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, контент сжат gzip или другим алгоритмом. Попробуйте это:

```
webRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

Comment: Да, действительно был сжат. Спасибо.